# Can I hold more than 10 healing items?

Tags: nier

After playing NieR: Automata, I decided I needed to play the original NIER. One thing I realized very early on is that I can't carry 99 healing items. Instead, I'm limited to a paltry 10 healing items.

While in the field, enemies drop them left and right, however, being unable to stock up on them means I run out *very* quickly in actual dungeons, which has led to me having to beat virtually every boss encounter with one or no healing items. This has caused me quite a bit of frustration.

Is there a way to carry more healing items? I know I can carry multiple *types* of healing items, but is there a way to carry more than 10 of any given type? That is, is there a way to carry 99 Medicinal Herbs or Health Salves, like I was able to carry 99 Small/Medium/Large Recovery items in NieR: Automata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After completing the game and getting all four endings, it looks like the maximum is 10 for each *type* of healing item. That is, rather than carrying 99 of a few healing items, you can to carry up to 10 of several types. In addition to the medicinal herbs and salves you can find or buy, you can also grow moon flowers in your garden and catch fish, both of which can be used to heal.

Therefore, you should carry as many *types* of healing items as possible is the best way to ensure you (shouldn't) run out during boss fights.